# SQL "WHERE" with Division

Tags: sql-server, database, where-clause

So, I want to have the product rating and apply this to get TOP PRODUCTS.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TopProducts]

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Prod_Name, Qty, ProductImage, Price, Store_Name
    FROM Product P, Store S
    WHERE ....
```

In my product table, you can find this :

```
(
Prod_ID int not null IDENTITY(1,1),
Store_ID int not null,
Price int not null ,
Prod_Name varchar(50) not null,
Qty int not null,
ProductDescription varchar(50),
RatingSum int not null,
RatingCount int not null,
ProductImage varchar(50),
Prod_Date date,
PRIMARY KEY (Prod_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Store_ID) REFERENCES Store(Store_ID)
);
```

So, I want to put in the "WHERE" condition, this : (RatingSum/RatingCount) >= 4 ... for example.

How can I do it?

EDIT:
To avoid confusion !
Rating sum, would be an int where the whole ratings from the reviewers will be added on each others, and rating count is something that increments each time a user reviews that specific product (This Prod_ID), after this, the rating is what you get from Dividing this by that !

Is there a better way to get the average rating for a specific product from multiple reviewers ?

Comment: What do you mean by "RatingSum/RatingCount"? Do you want to check both column values?

Comment: I want the rating, so I collect the whole rating sum, let's say (3,3,4,5) and divide it by the count which is (4) here. To get the average, obviously :D

Comment: @user3054349 . . . I don't understand.  `RatingSum` is a column as is `RatingCount`, so your question is about simple division.  If you have something else in mind, you should edit your question and include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Rating sum, would be an int where the whole ratings from the reviewers will be added on each others, and rating count is something that increments each time a user reviews that specific product (This Prod_ID), after this, the rating is what you get from Dividing this by that !

Comment: This is a simple `WHERE` condition. Did you even try what you have posted in your question?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't quiet work as I intended it to have worked !

Answer (score 5):

First, you can just do:

```
WHERE (RatingSum/RatingCount) >= 4
```

in your query.  To avoid division by zero, I would suggest changing this to:

```
WHERE RatingSum >= 4 * RatingCount >= 4
```

or:

```
WHERE (RatingSum/NULLIF(RatingCount, 0) >= 4
```

Also, you should never use comma in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Is it better if I used "Having" ?

And what's better to get a rating, this method I'm using or AVG(rating), where (rating) would be another attribute in the entity called (Product)?

Comment: `HAVING` should be used only for **aggregated** values - e.g. if you have a `SUM(...)` or `AVG(...)` and you need to apply a condition to that aggregate.